# java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException - when using split("\\");

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, exception

I'm solving [this problem](http://www.javaforschool.com/1903225-question-6-icse-2014-paper-solved-file-path-name/) in my own way. I'm trying to split the file path into Drive, folders, and file name, all into an array.

[Complete class. (Github)](https://github.com/Vikrant-G/Java-10-Practice/blob/master/filePath.java)

The problem:

```
String regex = "\\";
String [] divisions = path.split (regex);
```

This gives me an java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException. I looked up the [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) and found `[\b]`

```
String regex = "[\b]";
String [] divisions = path.split (regex);
```

This doesn't work. It doesn't throw an exception, nor does it split my file path based on backspace.

Input:

```
► Enter path -- 
C:\User\Admin\NekedGaben.jpg
```

Output:

```
→ Path = C:\User\Admin\NekedGaben.jpg
→ File name = C:\User\Admin\NekedGaben
→ Extension = .jpg
```

My questions:

1. Why does `"\\"` throw an exception, while `"[\b]"` doesn't?
2. Why doesn't the `split()` split the Path string?

Comment: What is ``\`` in regex? (Not ``"\\"``, that is a String literal.)

Comment: You want to read the wiki more carefully:  `[\b]` matches a back***space***, not a back***slash***.  Why would you ever want to match a backspace?  I don't know, I've never needed to.  But `\b` by itself matches a word boundary, and it can't mean that inside a character class, so its meaning arbitrarily changes to backspace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use double escaping in Java regex, i.e.:

```
String regex = "\\\\";
```

Or use static `Pattern.quote(String)` method:

```
String regex = Pattern.quote("\\");
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `\b` is a single character, the compiler knows it, they're friends.

However backslash (`\`) is represented by `\\` in Java, and `\` is *invalid* regex, in order to escape it, you should use:

```
\\\\
↓ ↓
escaping
```

Solution:

- Escape it as shown above
- Don't escape, let [`Pattern#quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) handle this for you